# cassandra java driver returns emptylist with composite key

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have a simple column family :

```
CREATE TABLE activesubs(
sub_id BIGINT, 
sub_data BLOB, 
user_id BIGINT,
user_data BLOB,
updated BIGINT,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, sub_id)
) WITH compaction = { 'class' : 'LeveledCompactionStrategy' };
```

when I query for all rows using cqlsh I get back the expected results set :

```
SELECT user_id from activesubs;
user_id
---------
2512
.....
4396

(83 rows)

cqlsh:game>
```

however when I try this using the java API I get 0 results back, the code is very simple:

```
Iterable<Row> results = session.execute("select user_id from activesubs") ;
```

I have played around and if I change the schema so that only sub_id is the primary key then the query works through the java api...

I am using the latest api version :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-rc2</version>
  </dependency>
```

Has anybody seen this before?  Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug with the api?